# How can I detect calls from different applications Messenger/Telegram/Viber etc. in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, call

Im using call-detection library to detect call state of phone calls and pause video if call is incoming, but it works only with phone calls, how can I detect state of app calls?

Answer (score 0):

there are many libraries for this. here is the simple one that I have used.

[react-native-callkeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-callkeep) and [react-native-call-detection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-detection) .

here the example

```
import CallDetectorManager from 'react-native-call-detection'
 
startListenerTapped() {
    this.callDetector = new CallDetectorManager((event, phoneNumber)=> {
    // For iOS event will be either "Connected",
    // "Disconnected","Dialing" and "Incoming"
 
    // For Android event will be either "Offhook",
    // "Disconnected", "Incoming" or "Missed"
    // phoneNumber should store caller/called number
 
 
    if (event === 'Disconnected') {
    // Do something call got disconnected
    }
    else if (event === 'Connected') {
    // Do something call got connected
    // This clause will only be executed for iOS
    }
    else if (event === 'Incoming') {
    // Do something call got incoming
    }
    else if (event === 'Dialing') {
    // Do something call got dialing
    // This clause will only be executed for iOS
    }
    else if (event === 'Offhook') {
    //Device call state: Off-hook.
    // At least one call exists that is dialing,
    // active, or on hold,
    // and no calls are ringing or waiting.
    // This clause will only be executed for Android
    }
    else if (event === 'Missed') {
        // Do something call got missed
        // This clause will only be executed for Android
  }
},
false, // if you want to read the phone number of the incoming call [ANDROID], otherwise false
()=>{}, // callback if your permission got denied [ANDROID] [only if you want to read incoming number] default: console.error
{
title: 'Phone State Permission',
message: 'This app needs access to your phone state in order to react and/or to adapt to incoming calls.'
} // a custom permission request message to explain to your user, why you need the permission [recommended] - this is the default one
)
}
 
stopListenerTapped() {
    this.callDetector && this.callDetector.dispose();
}
```

but there are some issues. for this you need sensitive permission like READ_SMS and PHONE_STATE for which you have to made your app default application. like default dialer or default SMS app. without this your application will be rejected by play store.

on another there is another way to detect call state. you can detect call state from notification and can use this library .

[react-native-android-notification-listener](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-notification-listener) you can modify this library according to your needs to filter for call notification. and call events. but notifications are handled different on different devices and brands. like on Samsung notifications have different object, on REALME and INFINIX notification are different. so you may also handle this. I have done this is about 6 months.,

there is also another issue that iOS it cant be done. because you are not allowed to any other application data.

Comment: As I mentioned in question description Im already using react-native-call-detection, but it only works with phone calls.

Comment: i have address other solutions. you can do it with notification listener.